# Keychron k3 battery status

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, macbook

I recently purchased a [keychron k3 keyboard](https://www.keychron.com/products/keychron-k3-wireless-mechanical-keyboard) which works perfectly fine on my macbook pro. Sadly, the keyboard lacks a battery indicator that is surfaced on the [macbook via the bluetooth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykWEI.png). I find the battery indicator very helpful as it can warn me in advance of low battery and won't leave me blocked when the battery dies. There is a way to check the battery level on the keyboard, but its not ideal for continuous monitoring.

is there a way for me to write a script to fetch this from the keyboard ? may be there are some apps that can help surface this information.

Comment: Hard to understand your question... Why isn't the OS battery indicator good enough?

Comment: Are you able to get a MacBook Pro keyboard?

Comment: Please see the attached screenshot in my question on the link "macbook via the bluetooth" of how connected bluetooth devices display battery levels on the macbook. I don't see the keychron k3 battery level on macbook. Since its a fairly new bluetooth keyboard, I believe it should be capable of sending that info to macbook.

Comment: Oh OK, that makes more sense now but the bad news are you can't do anything about it. There's no special support needed for that, no driver or software. The peripheral either informs the OS or it doesn't.

Comment: Wondering the same thing. Hope we get an answer!

Comment: Perhaps keep spare batteries in your drawer.